# Store output of php_execute_script

Tags: php, c, zend-framework, embed

How can I store the output of `php_execute_script()` in a character array? `php_execute_script()` only prints the output.
Here's what I've got:

```c
PHP_EMBED_START_BLOCK(argc, argv)

char string[200];
setbuf(stdout, string);
zend_file_handle file_handle;
zend_stream_init_filename(&file_handle, "say.php");
fflush(stdout);
if (php_execute_script(&file_handle) == FAILURE) {
    php_printf("Failed to execute PHP script.\n");
}
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
printf("\"%s\" is what say.php has to say.\n", string);

PHP_EMBED_END_BLOCK()
```

I've tried redirecting `stdout` to `string`, but it doesn't even look like `php_execute_script` is actually writing to `stdout`! It just ignores it.

I'm trying to communicate with the PHP embedded script ("say.php") from C using the PHP SAPI after building PHP with embedding enabled.

Comment: You could use an output buffer, but that's almost definitely the wrong way to do it.

Comment: Could you just use `exec` to run `say.php`  and then pipe that to an output buffer?

Comment: @BarryCarter I've tried that but it won't work (code posted above).

Comment: @quandaledingle I prefer using the API.

Comment: I meant using the ob functions: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php

Comment: @BarryCarter Oh. If that's what you meant, I don't think it's the best option as I'm writing a web server, so I'll have to use those functions in every webpage. There has to be an API func to do this, right? This was a piece of cake using the Python API. ;_;

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.execution.php (I was surprised to learn that PHP supports backticks just like the shell and Perl do)

Answer (score 0):

Thinking that there's no such thing, I made an issue:
https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/9330

```
#include <sapi/embed/php_embed.h>

char *string[999] = {NULL};
int i = 0;

static size_t embed_ub_write(const char *str, size_t str_length){
    string[i] = (char *) str; i++;
    return str_length;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    php_embed_module.ub_write = embed_ub_write;

    PHP_EMBED_START_BLOCK(argc, argv)

    zend_file_handle file_handle;
    zend_stream_init_filename(&file_handle, "say.php");

    if (php_execute_script(&file_handle) == FAILURE) {
        php_printf("Failed to execute PHP script.\n");
    }
    for (i = 0; string[i] != NULL; i++) {
        printf("%s", string[i]);
    }

    PHP_EMBED_END_BLOCK()
}
```

You need to set `php_embed_module.ub_write` to a callback function that gets called every time PHP makes an `echo`.
It's weird how PHP doesn't write to `stdout`...

EDIT: As it turns out, it does. You just need to use `pipe`.